# JAXP XSLT document() function problem

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan, jaxp

I am working under java application which uses XSLT transformation. I have a lot of document() calls in it, so it is possible to have java.lang.OutOfMemory exception (which I actually have), because after each call of document() function the document is cached.

At http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/faq.html#faq-N102F9 I read that it is possible to 
increase heap memory size which is not the solution in my case. I also tried to use incremental transform which seems to be not supported.

**So, is there any possibility to turn off document caching in jaxp while working with document() function?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like user1066037's answer, hopefully you can switch to Saxon. Saxon has an extension called `saxon:discard-document`. It's available in either the PE or EE editions or Saxon-B. Search for "Saxon-B" here: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

From the Saxon documentation:

> ### **saxon:discard-document()**
>
> **saxon:discard-document($doc as document-node()) ==> document-node()**
>
> This function removes a document from Saxon's internal document pool.
>   The document remains in memory for the time being, but will be
>   released from memory by the Java garbage collector when all references
>   to nodes in the document tree have gone out of scope. This has the
>   benefit of releasing memory, but the drawback is that if the same
>   document is loaded again during the same transformation, it will be
>   reparsed from the source text, and different node identifiers will be
>   allocated. The function returns the document node that was supplied as
>   an argument, allowing it to be used in a call such as
>   select="saxon:discard-document(document('a.xml'))".

If you need an example of how to use `saxon:discard-document`, let me know and I can post one.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided contains an example using a custom processing instruction to disable caching. Did you try the workaround suggested there?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a choice.

Just swap Xalan with Saxon and everything will be much faster and you may cut the memory consumption significantly.

From what I know, Xalan *will* load document into the memory, unless something has been changed in the latest release.

Saxon have streaming mode: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sourcedocs/streaming/streaming-templates.xml

Hope that helps.